# Wordpress gallery post doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I've been working on adding a gallery post on my blog, but whenever I add gallery it doesn't show the gallery itself. Instead it shows gallery shortcode on my post. Like this: [gallery ids="351,350"]. Is there any way to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Try the default theme or disable plugins.

Comment: No it didn't work. I tried but no success

Comment: If you just try add one gallery, does it show?

Comment: No, it doesn't, the Post itself doesn't show the gallery but whenever I click on read more it takes to the page where I can see my added images. Btw I am using John Doe's Blog theme. Here is the link: http://alpha1.dentalblog.az/home/ look at the 2nd post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to display galleries through `the_excerpt()`, but that's not supported by default.

### Idea 1:

You could try to add this to your `functions.php` file in the active theme's directory:

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode' );
```

But you should be careful with that setup, because the excerpt can cut through the shortcode:

```
Lorem Ipsum ... [gallery ids=" [...]
```

if the *excerpt text field* is empty and it's automatically generated from the *content text field*.

So you should consider using the *excerpt text field* in that case.

### Idea 2:

If you use `the_content()` instead, then you can use for example the `<!--more-->` quicktag in the post content:

```
 Lorem Ipsum ...
 [gallery ids="351,350"]
 ...
 <!--more-->
 ...
```

to control the excerpt part. But the downside is that you would have to do it for all your posts ;-)

Comment: I opened my functions.php, but I already have such function add_filter('the excerpt','do_shortcode') When used second idea, i wrote <!--more--> but again it didn't show the gallery. Are there any other ways I can make it work? Thank you!

Comment: ok, both ideas worked on my default themes. You can try for example to preview the default theme to check. I guess you have some special setup within your theme? What function does it use to display the excerpt?

Comment: It uses add_filter('the_excerpt','do_shortcode'), I don't have the_content() function in my functions.php

Comment: in my **gallery.php** page I can see this code: `<?php $post_excerpt = of_get_option('post_excerpt');
$folio_excerpt_count = of_get_option('folio_excerpt_count');  ?>`

Comment: It looks strange to have an option to store post_excerpt. Most likely you should start digging in the index.php file to find what's generating the excerpts. That search may take you through few files ;-)